# I have tried to find a mistake but there are none that I can see. The checkers dont see anything wrong

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

When I open it up as a html document the browser shows a white screen.
All of the html checkers are not helping I have tried what they said and it didn't work. I might just be understanding it wrong.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addeEventListener('load', eventWindowLoaded, false);
function eventWindowLoaded() {
    canvasApp();
}

function canvasApp(){
var theCanvas = document.getElementById('my_first_canvas');
var my_canvas = theCanvas.getContext('2d');

my_canvas.strokeRect(0,0,200,225)
my_canvas.beginPath();
my_canvas.arc(100, 100, 75, (Math.PI/180)*0, (Math.PI/180)*360, false);

my_canvas.strokeStyle = "black";
my_canvas.lineWidth = 3;
my_canvas.fillStyle = "yellow";

my_canvas.stroke();
my_canvas.fill();
my_canvas.closePath();

my_canvas.fillStyle = "black";
my_canvas.beginPath();
my_canvas.arc(65, 70, 10, (Math.PI/180)*0, (Math.PI/180)*360, false); 

my_canvas.stroke();
my_canvas.fill();
my_canvas.closePath();

my_canvas.beginPath();
my_canvas.arc(135, 70, 10, (Math.PI/180)*0, (Math.PI/180)*360, false);

my_canvas.stroke();
my_canvas.fill();
my_canvas.closePath();

my_canvas.lineWidth = 6;
my_canvas.beginPath();
my_canvas.arc(99, 120, 35, (Math.PI/180)*0, (Math.PI/180)*-180, false);

my_canvas.stroke();
my_canvas.closePath();

my_canvas.fillStyle = "black";
my_canvas.font      = '20px _sans';
my_canvas.fillText  ("Hello Canvas!", 45, 200);
}
</script>
```

I am trying to make a smiley face with canvas.

Comment: Can you show your html as well or even a complete jsfiddle?

Comment: document.getElementById() is Case SENSITIVE

Comment: I am moderately new to this. may I ask what that is.

Comment: I didn't realize that it was case sensitive ill check that

Comment: I updated what I did but Its is still blank I think there is a bigger mistake.

Comment: Change "window.addeEventListener" to "window.addEventListener". Open developer console and see if you have any errors there.

Comment: @Lajon how do I open a developer consel?

Comment: here is the link how to [open developer console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have a problem with the correct spelling of the names of functions. For example, `document.getelementbyid` actually `document.getElementById`. And there are a lot such errors.
Try to use browser console to detect them all.

Comment: It is like the linewidth I had it linewidth.Thank you I will try it and tell you if it is fixed.

Comment: It didn't work I think I fixed all the case sensitive mistakes but it is still blank